# Django cms don't append home page url

Tags: django-cms

I'm using DjangoCMS 2.3 and build all the pages in a tree structure beginning from the Index page. Right now all urls looks like this `/en/index/<page_url>`. How can I make cms ommit the `/index/` part and be just `/en/<page_url>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put the other pages bellow the home page. So instead of:

```
|-index (home page)
 |- page 1
  |- page 1.1
 |- page 2
```

you can do this:

```
|- index (home page)
|- page 1
 |- page 1.1
|- page 2
```

The first page in the tree is implicitly declared as the home page and marked with an icon in the page tree:

[image]